# write a recursive function to find hermite polynomials

Tags: python-2.7, recursion

# I have the recursive relationship of the Hermite Polynomials:

```
Hn+1(x)=2xHn(x)−2nHn−1(x), n≥1,

H0(x)=1, H1(x)=2x.
```

I need to write def hermite(x,n) for any hermite polynomial Hn(x) using python 2.7

and make a plot of H5(x) on the interval x∈[−1,1].

Answer (score 2):

Recursion is trivial here since the formula gives it. Just a small trap: you compute Hn(x), not Hn+1(x) so substract 1 to all `n` occurrences:

```
def hermite(x,n):
    if n==0:
        return 1
    elif n==1:
        return 2*x
    else:
        return 2*x*hermite(x,n-1)-2*(n-1)*hermite(x,n-2)
```

small test:

```
for i in range(0,5):
    print(hermite(1,i))

1
2
2
-4
-20
```

Comment: so to  find H5(x), should i put x=x and n=5? so hermite(x,5)

Comment: of course. something else would be surprising... I did not explain how to plot it though. I don't know matplotlib enough.

Comment: am not asking to plot it, i need to find the value of it. so when i print hermite(x,5), it gives me 11019589992.0,

Comment: for which `x` ? seems OK with x=1, see my edit. I manually verified `H(x,2)`, and it works, So, the rest should be OK (kind of "proof by recurrence").

Comment: well, x∈[−1,1].  so do I need to define x in my code?

Comment: so is there a way to find the value of H5(x), where x∈[−1,1], in term of x. for example when n=1, we get 2*x

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def HER(x,n):
    if n==0:
        return 1.0 + 0.0*x
    elif n==1:
        return 2.0*x
    else:
        return 2.0*x*HER(x,n-1) -2.0*(n-1)*HER(x,n-2)

xvals = np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,1000)
for N in np.arange(0,7,1):
    sol = HER(xvals,N)
    plt.plot(xvals,sol,label = "n = " + str(N))
plt.xticks(fontsize=14,fontweight="bold")
plt.yticks(fontsize=14,fontweight="bold")
plt.grid()
plt.legend()
plt.show()

#Code is working perfectly fine
```

Feel free to ask any question...

Comment: Can you edit your answer to include an explanation of how the code in your answer addresses the problem described in the question?

Comment: HI JohnH, I believe that the function I have defined represents the recursive relations of Hermite polynomials, which have already defined at the start of the problem (page). Here I have uploaded the full code along with graphical commands, just to confirm that we are on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.special import hermite



def HERMITE(X,N):
    HER = hermite(N)
    sn  = HER(X)
    return sn
xvals = np.linspace(-1.0,1.0,1000)
for n in np.arange(0,7,1):
    sol = HERMITE(xvals,n)
    plt.plot(xvals,sol,"-.",label = "n = " + str(n),linewidth=2)
plt.xticks(fontsize=14,fontweight="bold")
plt.yticks(fontsize=14,fontweight="bold")
plt.grid()
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is just another way to determine the Hermite polynomials with the help of an inbuilt library of Python.........